# The term "curl" what does it mean

Tags: curl, asana

in Asana developer guide each request mentioned the keyword "curl" what does it mean ? 
If I want to send the same request to get all workspace in java/ javascript what will be request parameter.

curl --request PUT -u : https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/1337 \
    -d "name=Everyone%27s Favorite Workspace"

in java .

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with `[java]`.

Comment: Hi peter, can't I develop the application using java Integrated with Asana. if yes coulld you please suggest how could i form the same url mentioned above to get response form server?

Answer (score 2):

> cURL is a computer software project providing a library and
>   command-line tool for transferring data using various protocols. The
>   cURL project produces two products, libcurl and cURL. It was first
>   released in 1997.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)